# Is it possible to output emojis in a CMD.EXE window with Python?

Tags: python, console, emoji

If I open a Command window tab in the Windows Terminal, either of the following methods would work correctly:

```py
print("\U0001F600")
```

```py
print("\N{grinning face}")
```

```py
from emoji import emojize
print(emojize(":grinning_face:"))
```

```py
from rich import print as rich_print
rich_print(":grinning_face:")
```

However, if I open a command window via Win+R CMD.EXE, neither of these methods works - a question mark in a square is displayed every time. Changing the code page to 65001 does not help, either. Importing `just_fix_windows_console` from `colorama` and running it before the printing also doesn't help - although it fixes the ability of printing ANSI escape sequences.

Both the CMD.EXE window and the Command window in Terminal use the same font - `Consolas`.

Is displaying emojis in a CMD.EXE window simply not possible or am I missing some trick that I don't know?

Comment: Yes, and you're doing it. Now you'll need to use a different terminal which uses a font that has glyphs for the emojis you want to use. FWIW, the standard Windows 11 terminal supports emojis just fine.

Comment: My question is whether it is possible in CMD.EXE. From googling around, it seems that the problem isn't in CMD.EXE or in the font it uses (as mentioned in my question, I use `Consolas` in both cases) but in`conhost.exe` that is used by CMD.EXE. Apparently Terminal does some magic with it. I was wondering if there is anything I could do.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with `cmd.exe`, which just outputs byte strings to the terminal it is running in using whatever encoding is being used.

So, if you run Python in Command Prompt, and get it to `print("\U0001F600")`, that character will be sent to the terminal.

However, the default Windows Console Host that used to be what you always opened when you ran Command Prompt on previous versions of Windows, does not support UTF-8 characters by default, it uses another encoding. So, you'll end up seeing this:

[image: A picture of a diamong character with a question mark]

However, on Windows 11 the new Windows Terminal is the default, and it does have full support and uses UTF-8 by default. If you run Command Prompt using the Windows terminal, you get this:

[image]

It's easy to confuse the command interpreter (the actual CLI application) and the terminal it is running in to show what is going on with the input and output streams for the command interpreter.

PowerShell and Command Prompt are command interpreters. Windows Console Host and Windows Terminal are terminals. It's the choice of the latter that limits what can be rendered. The former both support many encodings.

Note that you can also download and install Windows Terminal on Windows 10 - it's just not the default.

Note: you asked if there's anything you can do. You can and [this question goes into that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window), but also note that this is *not recommended* and has far-reaching impact on other applications. You definitely wouldn't want to force other users of your Python script to have to do the same. Windows Terminal is here to stay, so using it as the new default is the better option.

Comment: So, basically it's not possible? The link you provided doesn't help - as I already mentioned in my question, changing the code page to 65001 does not solve the problem. Yes, I'm on Windows 10. I do have Terminal but I was wondering if I could solve the problem in CMD.EXE. Guess not. :(

Comment: It's possible - the accepted answer on the linked page goes into more than just changing the codepage for the active console host. However, as I said before, you really, really shouldn't. This is not a good idea, even if it works. Your comment suggests that you didn't understand my answer. The problem is *not* with cmd.exe, it's with the Windows Console Host - not the same thing. But there's little point in repeating the answer in the comments. You can run either Command Prompt or PowerShell in Console Host or Terminal. All 4 combinations work, only 2 have UTF-8 support, with Terminal.

Comment: I *do* understand that the problem is in `conhost.exe` and not in `cmd.exe` - in fact, I said the same thing in a comment to the question. Oh, well. Thanks anyway.